# Page Number In docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I am wondering how I can get page number in docx4j

My issue is that I created a table and have to remove some borders between some rows but that made table with no bottom borders before page break [image]
So I need information about page number to do something like this

```
 if(currentElementPageNumber != precedentElementPageNumber)
 ctBorderTop.setVal(STBorder.Double);
 tcBorder.setTop(ctBorderBottom);
 tcpr2.setTcBorders(tcBorder);
```

Or a way to detect page break, any ideas would be helpfull

Comment: Bear in mind that you can tell a row not to break across pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work arround this 
what i did is make table border without insideH border

`CTBorder nilBorder= new CTBorder();
ctBorder.setVal(STBorder.NIL); 
tblBorders.setInsideH(nilBorder);`

then add bottom border to row depends on my condition

Answer (score 0):

You can include a bookmark, then send it to the commercial PDF Converter to get the information back as JSON.  See https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc/TocGenerator.java#L763 to get an idea

See also [Conditional Formatting in Microsoft Word 2016 Table Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711329/conditional-formatting-in-microsoft-word-2016-table-cells) for other ideas